# Entire functions $f,g,h$ with $e^f+e^g+e^h \equiv 0$ implies $f,g,h$ only differ by constant

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show complex entire functions $f,g,h$ with $e^f+e^g+e^h \equiv 0$ implies $f,g,h$ only differ by constant?

#### Progress

I tried using Picard's theorem. In the equation $e^{f−h}+e^{g−h}+1\equiv 0$, is it possible for  $e^{f−h}$ and $e^{g−h}$ to cancel each other out?

Comment: Have you already heard of Picard's (little) theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes I know that. I tried using that theorem but still not work it out.. Could you give some more specific hints? Thank you!

Comment: Multiply with $e^{-h}$. See that $f-h$ and $g-h$ must leave out too many values to not be constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer can $e^{f-h}$ and $e^{g-h}$ cancel out each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After multiplying with $e^{-h}$ and renaming, we have the identity

$$e^{\tilde{f}} + e^{\tilde{g}} \equiv -1.$$

We know one value that neither $e^{\tilde{f}}$ nor $e^{\tilde{g}}$ ever attains. Therefore we know another value that these functions never attain. By Picard's (little) theorem, $e^{\tilde{f}}$ and $e^{\tilde{g}}$ are constant.